# Laptop touchpad is NOT detected!

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 on an Acer V5-123 netbook. If the specs matter, then the netbook has an AMD E1-2K with 4GB of RAM. The system is regularly updated and has all the latest stuff from the main server.

Till a few updates ago, the touchpad was working absolutely fine. Unfortunately, I don't use this netbook for my day-to-day work and so I had not updated it for like a few weeks. I updated it today (Sep 10, 2014) and multiple issues seem to have cropped up! But, the issue that concerns us here is: the touchpad is NOT detected at all on the system.

I opened the mouse-n-touchpad section of the `xfce4-settings-manager` and there's no touchpad there. So, I ran `lsusb` and there's no touchpad there either!

I pulled out the Xubuntu HDD and re-inserted the Windows 8.1 HDD that came with this notebook and everything works as expected: touchpad and everything else.

Can you help me figure out why Xubuntu is not detecting the touchpad hardware? Is this a bug in the kernel I have? The kernel version on my system is: `3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried logging in as guest to see if the issue affects all users?

Comment: yes @mchid, i tried logging in as 2 different users: user-1 and as guest. my guess is that since lspci and lsusb fail to show the touchpad this could be a kernel issue. but that's just my feeling.

Comment: Unless you uninstalled the old kernels, you should still be able to boot one of the old ones from the grub menu, select extra options (or something like that) for a list of installed kernels to boot from.

Comment: Yikes! That is where the bigger problem lies. I have multiple systems running XU 14.04 at home. I also have very limited bandwidth. So, to save my "precious" bandwidth, I have put together a script that essentially puts the entire /var/cache/apt/archives onto an external hdd and then updates the system. Unfortunately, at the end of that script I have "apt-get autoremove -y" which purges the old kernels. I will comment it out so I don't purge the old kernels till I have checked the new kernels. But for now I don't have the old kernels. :(

Comment: You're in luck. you can actually install one of the older kernels using apt-get. For example: `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic` and you can go all the way back to linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic and you can install any kernel version in-between.

Comment: Also, it might sound silly but did you check your fn keys. I've accidentally toggled the hardware switch without noticing.

Comment: Checked, after you suggested. Still no response! :( (BTW, @mchid, thanks a lot for your support on this. Also, you win in my book because of the kitteh photo you have as ur profile. :) )